# Circle Tangents Questions

Tags: geometry

(1) Triangle $ABC$, inscribed in a circle, has $AB = 15$ and $BC = 25$. A tangent to the circle is drawn at $B$, and a line through $A$ parallel to this tangent intersects $\overline{BC}$ at $D$. Find $DC$.

[image: diagram1]

(2) Let the incircle of triangle $ABC$ be tangent to sides $\overline{BC}$, $\overline{AC}$, and $\overline{AB}$ at $D$, $E$, and $F$, respectively. Prove that triangle $DEF$ is acute.

[image: diagram2]

I have tried several angle and arc formulas... but I can't get anywhere...

Comment: Hint for (1): look for similar triangles.

Comment: I am not convinced that lengh DC remains constant whatever be the shape of triangle ABC, but maybe I am wrong...

Comment: You mean for all angles  at B?

Answer (score 2):

HINTS.

(1) Triangles $CBA$ and $ABD$ are similar. Exploit that to find $BD$.

(2) The incenter of $ABC$ lies inside $DEF$, because it is the intersection of the angle bisectors.

Comment: I am not doubting your answer but i cant seems to get $\angle BAD = \angle ACB$. How did you get it ?, sorry.

Comment: @ritwiksinha $\angle BDA=\angle DBX=\angle CAB$ ($X$ is any point on the tangent away from $A$(downwards) ). Hence your doubt is cleared

Comment: @ritwiksinha If $E$ is the other intersection between line $AD$ and the circle, then arcs $AB$ and $BE$ are equal.